# Ruby - writing a basic controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails and trying to write some of the code by hand so that I learn how it works.

I made this tiny controller:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def test

      def show
        render :text => "Hi from TestsController!"
      end  

  end
end
```

and this is what is left of my view:

```
<h3> Hello test </h3>
```

and this is my routes.rb snippet:

```
resource :test
```

but it gives an error that: `The action 'show' could not be found for TestsController`

Thanks!

This is the output of rake routes:

```
home_index GET    /home/index(.:format) home#index
      root        /                     home#index
      test POST   /test(.:format)       tests#create
  new_test GET    /test/new(.:format)   tests#new
 edit_test GET    /test/edit(.:format)  tests#edit
           GET    /test(.:format)       tests#show
           PUT    /test(.:format)       tests#update
           DELETE /test(.:format)       tests#destroy
```

Comment: what are html tags doing here? update your controller to fit the klump's answer.

Comment: @shime I put the html tags there because in the tutorials, in the index.html.erb there was html tags. So I thought that is how it is done.  Otherwise, how do I specify what to html to render once the controller executes?

Comment: @GeekedOut index.html.erb [isn't the controller, it's the view.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture)

Comment: This controller renders view located at `app/views/tests/show.html.erb`. Remove the html from your controller and put it there. I would refer to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) if I were you, since this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Ah, but what confused me is that the index.html.erb is a view, but a file with a similarly patterned name test.html.erb is a controller.  How could that be? Or is the thing that matters is the directory location? Sorry, still a bit confused.

Comment: My test.html.erb file is under app/views/home/test.html.erb so I guess it is a view also.

Comment: So in my routes.rb I have this route:   resource :test   ...does this mean that it bypassed the controller? How do I make it go to a controller first before going to the view?

Comment: @GeekedOut Your question indicates that you really don't yet understand the MVC pattern. I recommend you take a look at [this diagram](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:mvc_in_action) and read the difference between the Router, Controller, View and Model.

Comment: @ghoppe I do understand the pattern, I am just learning how it works in Ruby. I was expecting to have first called a controller after which a view would execute, but I am not sure whether what I specified in my code possibly skips the controller.

Comment: @GeekedOut The problem is the `def test` block. Why did you add that? That's why the `show` method isn't found.

Comment: @ghoppe when I made the controller exactly like klump's example, it gave me this error: Missing template tests/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Sites/blog/app/views"

Comment: @GeekedOut Where is your template and View? There should be a view at `app/views/test/show.html.erb` and a template at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: I guess those would be files auto-generated if I ran the command to auto-generate the 7 crud files?

Comment: @ghoppe my view is app/views/test.html.erb was that the wrong thing to name it?

Comment: @ghoppe `def` is not a block.

Comment: @GeekedOut don't you ever auto-generate. remove the `def test` from your controller. create a new file inside `app/views/test/show.html.erb` and put your html inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A basic controller looks like this:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

You do not need the `respond_to` block if you only want to render the default view (in this case: `app/views/tests/show.html.erb`). The `respond_to` block is when you have some more advanced needs.

Comment: I suggest adding just `render :text => "Hi from TestsController!"` inside the action. It's simpler.

Comment: @klump I just changed the code to implement your change and I still get this error: "The action 'show' could not be found for TestsController" ...should I implement rake routes every time I make a change?

Comment: @GeekedOut you don't implement `rake routes`. `rake routes` is a tool for showing which routes are defined in `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: @shime ah thanks! So in my case, any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 2):

What @klump said is correct. Try running a basic scaffold. This will generate a controller, model and views for you. This generator is great when you are learning rails.

```
 rails g scaffold Test
```

Also check out http://www.railsforzombies.com as it is a great way to learn rails.

Comment: thanks. I was trying to write all these by hand just to see what all the moving parts are. In your command what is the "g" for?

Comment: @GeekedOut g is short for `generate`. Try `rails help`.

Comment: @GeekedOut By the way, you are writing everything out by hand, but how do you know which moving parts you need? The error you were receiving "Missing template" makes it pretty clear you're missing the template. :)

Comment: @ghoppe :) I think working through the errors is a good way to learn ...maybe I am wrong...tinkering with the scaffold thing now. Although I recall someone telling me before that scaffold might be overkill and add bloat to the app.  No?

Comment: @GeekedOut If you're worried about the scaffold being overkill and adding bloat, perhaps Rails isn't the framework you're looking for. :) Rails favours convention over configuration. The whole point of the scaffold is to decrease the number of decisions you have to make, so that all the conventional parts are in place and you, the developer, only have to worry about the non-conventional parts of your app.

Comment: @GeekedOut in my opinion, you should go through the rails for zombies course and build things with the generators. Try using the scaffold generator, the controller and model generator. Look at how they are put together in a working order then tweek them. Also you may just want to pick up a book on Ruby on Rails. :)

Comment: way to go @ericraio. scaffolding is the worst way of learning if you're a newbie. don't you ever use "scaffold" if you're trying to learn how something works. maybe it's just me, but you'll learn a lot more without generators

Comment: @shime I think it is just you. I learned a lot by generating a scaffold, looking at the output of what was generated, then taking it apart piece by piece. A valid way to learn how something works is to observe how something is built and inspect the constituent parts. There's also an argument to be made that you don't need to know how the deeper parts of rails work in order to build a useful application. I don't need to know how registers and assembly commands work in order to make a loop in ruby.

Comment: @shime also when you scaffold something together, you get a small bite size application that will work in front of you on your local machine. From there you can see how each piece works and in my opinion, it gives you hands on experience. You will learn rails easier when you build on top of it to add more functionality to the scaffold. When you are learning rails the first time, it's great.

Comment: @ericraio so what's your argument in using scaffolds? seeing how something works? why don't use sinatra instead? there you build everything from scratch and you can separate everything in multiple files, follow the rules of MVC, etc. I think it's way better. Build something from scratch and don't use any predefined "generators".

Answer (score 1):

You use `respond_to` when you want your action to respond to multiple formats. Client sets it's desired format in HTTP Accept header.

You can then specify different action for each format.

#### Example

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html { Rails.logger.debug "rendering show.html" }
       format.xml { Rails.logger.debug "rendering show.xml" }
       format.js { Rails.logger.debug "rendering show.js" }
    end
end
```

Refer to the [API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) for more examples.